# Rails Active Storage Variant Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

#### Steps to reproduce

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
   has_many_attached :images
end
```

In view:

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(@product.images.first.variant(resize: "100x100", flip: "-90"))) %>
```

#### Expected behaviour

The image is supposed to be shown flipped

#### Actual behavior

The image is not loading,

[image]

In Logs I have

```
MiniMagick::Error (`mogrify -flip -90 /tmp/mini_magick20180808-26054-yjj6f4.jpg` failed with error:
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `-90': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
mogrify-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
):
```

while below options work properly

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(@product.images.first.variant(resize: "100x100"))) %>
<%= image_tag(url_for(@product.images.first.variant(resize: "100x100", rotate: "-180"))) %>
<%= image_tag(url_for(@product.images.first.variant(resize: "100x100", rotate: "-180", monochrome: true))) %>
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 5.2

**Ruby version**: 2.3.3

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with rails 5.2 and ruby 2.4.1. The strange thing is that I have two dummy app, same Gem file, one is working perfectly the other fails. I tried to drill down, but I sill can not find out what's happening.

Comment: Okay, actually I have understood the problem to some extent, please check if ImageMagick is installed on your system first, I guess it should be there. Secondly checkout `https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php` and `http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php` ,  flip being used by me doesn't receive any other argument in command line, so I had to write flip: nil which works

Comment: Very good! `flip: nil` did the trick. Anyway, on one of my app `flip: "-90"` is working as well. I suggest you post a self reply.